# Javascript web browser script not working

Tags: javascript, browser

Internet Explorer 7 does not handle buttons correctly since it sends the text between `<button>` and `</button>`rather than the value. (Weird but true.) This Javascript is supposed to correct this by sending the value of the button `onClick`. But it does not work. Can anybody see the error ?

I use this to attach the Javascript file in HTML5 :

```
<script src="buttonfix.js"></script>
```

Contents of buttonfix.js :

```
function runonclick()
{
    var count = 0;
    var formlength = this.form.elements.length;
    while(count < formlength)
    {
        if(this.form.elements[count].tagName === "button")
        {
            this.value = this.attributes.getNamedItem("value").nodeValue;
        }

        count++;
    }
}

function buttonfix()
{
    var buttonarray = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    var count = 0;
    var buttonarraylength = buttonarray.length;
    while(count < buttonarraylength)
    {
        buttonarray[count].onClick = runonclick();

        count++;
    }
}

window.attachEvent("onload", buttonfix());
```

Comment: What exactly *does not work*?

Comment: @Felix Kling The Javascript does not make the button send the value instead of the text. I used jslint so the problem must not be syntax related.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try:

```
if(this.form.elements[count].tagName.toLowerCase == "button");
```

instead of:

```
if(this.form.elements[count].tagName == "button")
```

because the `tagName` property generally returns an uppercased string.

Another line does not work:

```
buttonarray[count].onClick = runonclick();
```

As JavaScript it is a case-sensitive language, you have to use the standard name of the event (`onclick`).

```
buttonarray[count].onclick = runonclick();
```

However, you may still to use `onClick` in your HTML (but not XHTML).